# open-device in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I am using powershell to connect to a Windows Phone 8 device. Open-Device was being used before to accomplish this in windows 7, but there is something different going on in windows 8, and I'm not sure what it is. When I run it now, it responds that it does not recognize the cmdlet, function, program, etc.. What does it take to be able to run "open-device" in Windows 8?

For some background, this is for installing an app on a Windows Phone 8 using a .xap file and a .xml license file.

Sorry if the info isn't as thorough as it could be, I'm just an intern with no idea what's actually going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Give windows phone 8 IP address

open-device "0.0.0.0"

or

Open-Device -DeviceIPAddress "0.0.0.0"